# how to calculate exact php upload limits

Tags: apache-2.2, php, upload, maximum

maximum size of uploads in php depend on number of settings. here they are, as put into apache virtual hosts file:

```
php_admin_flag file_uploads on

php_admin_value memory_limit 560M
php_admin_value post_max_size 530M
php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 500M

php_admin_value max_execution_time 0
php_admin_value max_input_time 0
```

please ignore the values above, but they enable me to allow uploads of around 150-200M. memory_limit, post_max_size and upload_max_filesize have some specific ratios between each other. i believe that

```
upload_max_filesize < post_max_size < memory_limit
```

however, i dont' know how to calculate exact sizes. for example what must be values of these settings in order to allow exactly 100M file upload? from what i gathered online, there is number of factors that determine these ratios, but i couldn't find any references what are these factors.

i'm using linux system.

Answer (score 1):

The memory limit is independent of the POST size you upload files. The uploaded files will be parsed directly by PHP and put in a temp folder.

The `upload_max_filesize` must be 100M and your `post_max_size` must be 100M + the overhead of the multipart encoding. The overhead is low as it is binary encoded with a boundary. Even with 101MB it will work.

Now, it may still crash your script if you then do `$file = file_get_contents('path/to/uploaded/file.ext');` because in this case the `memory_limit` will kick in.